# JQuery code conflict?

Tags: jquery

1st off let me say thanks for taking the time to read my problem.

I am new to jquery and just tring to learn.

What I am trying to do is make a slide in panel for my website.

I have taken some code from an online example here : http://www.dzyngiri.com/index.php/sliding-panel-menu-using-jquery/

I have pretty much the same code as posted however I when I add it to my website it gives me a white page and the error is internal 500 , now I know my server is working properly and I have narrowed the problem down to one line of code.

This line of code comes rite after  :

```
    setTimeout( function(){$('#staffmenu').css('right','-160px');},100); <!-- Change 'left' to 'right' for panel to appear to the right -->
```

what am I doing wrong ?  I have run the same code just in a html file and it works fine, is it because the functions have no names ?

any help or a kick in the rite direction is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What does Firebug tell you?

Comment: The issues doesn't come from the JavaScript. JavaScript cannot make browser response with 500 Internal Error. Something wrong with your programming language

Comment: No answer to your question yet?

Answer (score 3):

500 is a server error that the page not respond.

If you wrote that comment in your code, it is wrong.

`<!-- ... -->` is used for HTML.

For Javascript use:

`//` for single row comment and

`/* ... */` for multiple row comment

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will never ever make the server return an Internal Server Error 500.

Also I wonder why you use html-comment in javascript code?

```
setTimeout( function(){$('#staffmenu').css('right','-160px');},100); <!-- Change 'left' to 'right' for panel to appear to the right -->
```

should be

```
setTimeout( function(){$('#staffmenu').css('right','-160px');},100); // Change 'left' to 'right' for panel to appear to the right
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error page (404, 500, etc), the problem is at the server.

jQuery is a javascript library, and library is run at client side. That means that even if jQuery fails, that would only disable a part of your website's functionality, not display an error page.

The 500 error code is a kind of "catch-all" of errors. Something went wrong at the server, but cant tell what because the server cant find the cause.

I surely cant tell you what to do to fix it.

---

Edit: Remove the comment tags `<!-- ... -->` in that line as Andrea Turri suggested. I have my doubts that will fix the 500, but it shouldn't be there.